# Populate ConcurrentDictionary from Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

How can i populate the data from `Dictionary` to `ConcurrentDictionary`.

I have following,

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var names = new List<Employee> 
{
    new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Name1" },
    new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Name1" },
    new Employee { Id = 2, Name = "Name2" },
    new Employee { Id = 3, Name = "Name3" },
};
```

and i populate to `Dictionary` like,

```
Dictionary<int, List<Employee>> dict = names.GroupBy(n => n.Id).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

and I want to create,

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<Employee>> concDict
```

and i tried,

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<Employee>> concDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<Employee>>();
dict.ToList().ForEach(e => concDict.TryAdd(e.Key, e.Value));
```

Is there any built-in extension method like `.ToDictionary`?

Comment: @Down/Close Voter. I'm fine for down vote. Have you dare to comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the `Dictionary<T>` into one of the `ConcurrentDictionary<T>` [constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287236%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I don't think there's an extension method to do it directly, but it shouldn't be too difficult to write one if you want to avoid all the extra object creation.

```
public static ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TElement> ToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector)
{
    var dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TElement>();
    foreach (TSource local in source)
    {
        dictionary.TryAdd(keySelector(local), elementSelector(local));
    }
    return dictionary;
}
```

Comment: It is dictionary.TryAdd(). not dictionary.Add(). Please correct it.

Comment: Sorry, I have LinqPad for .NET 3.5 running, which doesn't have ConcurrentDictionary.  I based the example on `ToDictionary`.  I'll edit the code.